# Derivative of pseudoinverse with respect to original matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

I have been trying to find an analytical expression for the following:

$\frac{\partial {X^{+}}}{\partial {X}}$

In my case, $X$ has a constant rank.
I've found the formula for differentiating a pseudoinverse in [Goulob's paper](http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/72/261/CS-TR-72-261.pdf) (equation 4.12):

$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} A^+(x) =
 -A^+ \left( \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} A \right) A^+
+A^+ A{^+}^T  \left( \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} A^T \right) (1-A A^+)
+ (1-A^+ A) \left( \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} A^T \right) A{^+}^T A^+
$$

but I can't see how to input the original matrix. I've tried

$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d A} A^+(A) =
 -A^+ \left( \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d A} A \right) A^+
+A^+ A{^+}^T  \left( \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d A} A^T \right) (1-A A^+)
+ (1-A^+ A) \left( \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d A} A^T \right) A{^+}^T A^+
$$

but it doesn't seem to give the right answers. What should $\frac{\mathrm d A^T}{\mathrm d A}$ and $\frac{\mathrm d A}{\mathrm d A}$ evaluate to?

Comment: X-posting with impunity: http://mathoverflow.net/q/264130/91764

Comment: Hi Rodrigo- wasn't sure which it belonged to. Happy to delete the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A matrix-matrix gradient will be a 4th order tensor. So it's easier to start with the differential, since that is an ordinary matrix.

For ease of typing, I'll use $P$ for the pseudoinverse of $A$. It's differential is
$$\eqalign{
  dP &= PP^T\,dA^T\,(I-AP) + (I-PA)\,dA^T\,P^TP -P\,dA\,P \cr\cr
}$$
Next we need to factor out $\,dA,\,$ for which we'll need two special 4th order tensors 
$$\eqalign{
{\mathcal B}_{ijkl} = \delta_{il}\,\delta_{jk} \cr
{\mathcal E}_{ijkl} = \delta_{ik}\,\delta_{jl} \cr
}$$
These tensors can be used to transpose matrices and to rearrange the order of matrix products 
$$\eqalign{
X^T &= {\mathcal B}:X \cr
 A\,X\,B &= A{\mathcal E}B^T:X \cr
}$$
where colon represents the inner (Frobenius) product.

Continuing with the pseudoinverse
$$\eqalign{
  dP
 &= \Big(PP^T{\mathcal E}(I-AP)^T:{\mathcal B} + (I-PA){\mathcal E}P^TP:{\mathcal B} -P{\mathcal E}P^T\Big):dA \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial P}{\partial A}
 &= \Big(PP^T{\mathcal E}(I-AP)^T + (I-PA){\mathcal E}P^TP\Big):{\mathcal B} -P{\mathcal E}P^T \cr\cr
}$$
Interestingly, the answer to your last question is
$$\eqalign{
 {\mathcal B} &= \frac{\partial A^T}{\partial A},\,\,&\,\, {\mathcal E} &= \frac{\partial A}{\partial A} \cr
}$$

Comment: Thank you - this is amazing. I'm trying to understand the inner product in terms of index notation (I've only ever taken the inner product of two matrices with the same order). Do you take the inner product over the trailing dimensions? So if A is 4th order, and B is 2nd order, would it be correct to say that $(A:B)_{ij} = \sum_{kl} A_{ijkl} B_{kl}$?

Comment: And for that matter, I assume the n-dimensional dot product of is the sum-product over the last and second-to-last dimensions. So for two 4th order  tensors, $(AB)_{ijklmn} = \sum_x A_{ijkx} B_{lmxn}$. Is this right?

Comment: No need to reply to above - I tested it all and it works perfectly. Thanks again. Do you recommend any resources for getting a better grasp of this stuff?

Comment: I'm now trying to get it to work on rectangular matrices (I tested on square). If $A$ is $m \times n$, what dimensions would ${\mathcal E}$ and ${\mathcal B}$ be? I assumed it would be $\text{dim}B = \left( N \times M \times M \times N \right)$ and  $\text{dim}E = \left( N \times M \times N \times M \right)$, but it doesn't seem like this works.

Comment: Ah, I see what I'm doing wrong- they don't have the same dimensions each time you use them, you set the dimensions as required in each case.

Comment: I'm using the convention where juxtapostion $(C=AB)$ implies a single contraction product  $$C_{ik}=A_{ij}B_{jk}$$ while the Frobenius product $(\alpha=A:B)$ is a double-contraction product $$\alpha=A_{ij}B_{ij}$$ Extending this to 4th order tensors $(C=A{\mathcal E}:B)$ really means $$C_{ik}=A_{ij}{\mathcal E}_{jklm}B_{lm}$$ NB: I've used the Einstein convention in all of these expressions, whereby a repeated dummy index implies summation over that index. And yes, the dimensions are set implicitly each time you use the tensors.

Comment: If you are writing computer code, don't explicitly allocate these tensors, but rather translate them into if-conditions.  For example, ${\mathcal E}_{ijkm}$ translates to the condition $$ $$ IF( i==k && j==m ) THEN this_term_is_not_zero $$ $$

Comment: Thanks - I'm not completely sure what you mean. Which tensor are you indexing?

I'm currently explicitly allocating the tensors as you mentioned: i.e. my code for $P{\mathcal E}P^T$ is something like `matmul(P, E(M,N), P.transpose)`, where `E(M,N)` builds the 4th order $\mathcal E$ tensor.

Comment: It turns out that I can replace $A \mathcal{E} B$ in my code with the elementwise product of A and B and it gives the same answer, but I still can't figure out a working expression for when the original matrix is rectangular (this results in the matrices on either side of $\mathcal{E} $ having different dimensions, so the elementwise product doesn't make sense).