# Derivative of an elementwise function and a pesudoinverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, pseudoinverse

I am trying to compute the partial derivatives of the following discrete time dynamic system with respect to $A$ and $B$ (for linearization purposes):

$$
B_{t+1} = yf(A_tx)^\dagger\\
A_{t+1} = f^{-1}(B_t^\dagger y)x^\dagger
$$

Where $f$ is an element-wise invertible function, $x$ and $y$ are static fat matrices, and $A$ and $B$ are matrices of requisite size.

In [Derivative of pseudoinverse with respect to original matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179160/derivative-of-pseudoinverse-with-respect-to-original-matrix), @user1551 introduces an $e$ and and $E$ that is used to help with the differentiation - but I haven't been able to follow well enough to do it on my own.

Comment: If you do not improve your question, you will never have an answer.  What are exactly $(A_tx)^\dagger$, $A,B,A_t,B_t,x,y,f$; in particular $f$  goes from what into what... Are $A,B$ initial values. The pseudo-inverse is denoted by $U^+$ , where is it ? What is exactly the dimension of each considered matrix ? In your two equalities, there are  missing parentheses. What is  "an element-wise invertible function" ?  Are "static fat matrices"  constant matrices ?

Comment: @loupblanc sorry. $(A_tx)^\dagger$ is the pesudoinverse of the matrix-matrix product $A_tx$. $f$ is an elementwise invertible nonlinear function, like sigmoid -- this is a common idea where the elements are evaluated through the function point-wise (so $f(A) = f(A_{ij})$ for all the elements of $A$) I'm not sure what you mean by missing parentheses. And static fat matrices means constant matrices whose column dimension far exceeds it's row dimension.

Comment: $A_0$ and $B_0$ would be initial values for $A_t$ and $B_t$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $F=f(AX)$, then it appears you are trying to solve 
$$Y = BF$$
using some kind of alternating directions iteration.

But given *any* $A$ you can solve explicitly for $B$ 
$$\eqalign{
B &= YF^++M(I-FF^+) \cr
}$$
Conversely, given **any** $B$ you can solve for $A$ 
$$\eqalign{
F &= B^+Y+L(I-B^+B) \cr
G &= f^{-1}(F) \cr
A &= GX^++K(I-XX^+) \cr
}$$
**NB:** In the above $(K,L,M)$ are arbitrary matrices. In your iteration it appears you have set them all to zero, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
B &= YF^+ \cr
F &= B^+Y \cr
A &= GX^+\cr
}$$

Although you can solve for either matrix given the other, in order to solve for them simultaneously you'll need a constraint equation.