# Gradient of $\lVert \mathbf{H}^{\dagger}\mathbf{H} - \mathbf{B}\rVert_F^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, pseudoinverse

I'm trying to get the derivative of

$$f(\mathbf{H})=\lVert \mathbf{H}^{\dagger}\mathbf{H} - \mathbf{B}\rVert^2_F$$

with respect to $\mathbf{H}$, where $\mathbf{H}^\dagger$ denotes the pseudo-inverse of $\mathbf{H}$.

I know that $\nabla f = \mathbf{J}_{\mathbf{H}^{\dagger}\mathbf{H}}(\mathbf{H})^T \cdot \text{vect}\left(2(\mathbf{H}^{\dagger}\mathbf{H}-\mathbf{B}) \right)$ where $\mathbf{J}_{\mathbf{H}^{\dagger}\mathbf{H}}(\mathbf{H})$ is the Jacobian Matrix of $\mathbf{H}^{\dagger}\mathbf{H}$.

By the other hand, from "Matrix Cook Book", I know that

- $d(\mathbf{H}^\dagger\mathbf{H}) = d(\mathbf{H}^\dagger)\mathbf{H} + \mathbf{H}^\dagger d(\mathbf{H}) $

and from [Derivative of pseudoinverse with respect to original matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179160/derivative-of-pseudoinverse-with-respect-to-original-matrix) I know that

- $\eqalign{d\mathbf{H}^\dagger &= \mathbf{H}^\dagger (\mathbf{H}^\dagger)^T\,d\mathbf{H}^T\,(\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{H}\mathbf{H}^\dagger) + (\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{H}^\dagger \mathbf{H})\,d\mathbf{H}^T\,(\mathbf{H}^\dagger)^T\mathbf{H}^\dagger -\mathbf{H}^\dagger\,d\mathbf{H}\,\mathbf{H}^\dagger \cr
  }$

But I don't know how to use the last two differential, I mean, how can I obtain $\mathbf{J}_{\mathbf{H}^{\dagger}\mathbf{H}}(\mathbf{H})$ or $\partial (\mathbf{H}^{\dagger}\mathbf{H})_{(i,j)}/\partial \mathbf{H}_{(k,l)}$?

Comment: Usually, $+$ is used to denote the pseudoinverse, while $\dagger$ is used to denote the Hermitian transpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $H$ is a poor choice for the name of the matrix, since it is easily confused with the Hermitian conjugate operation (likewise, the ubiquity of the transpose operation makes $T$ a bad choice).

So let's define the following matrices
$$\eqalign{
X &= H \quad\; {\rm (independent\,variable)} \cr
P &= X^\dagger \quad {\rm (pseudo\,inverse\,of\,X)} \cr
A &= PX-B \cr
dA &= d\,(PX) \cr
 &= dP\,X + P\,dX \cr
 &= -P\,dX\,PX + (I-PX)\,dX^H\,P^H \quad+\quad P\,dX \cr
 &= P\,dX\,(I-PX) + (I-PX)\,dX^H\,P^H \cr
}$$
**NB:**   The relationships
$$\eqalign{
&(I-XP)X =(X-X)= 0 \\
&P^HPX = P^H \\
}$$
were used to eliminate some terms.

Write the function in terms of these new variables.

Then find its differential and gradient. 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= A^*:A \cr
df &= A^*:dA \quad&+\; conj \cr
 &= A^*:\Big(P\,dX\,(I-PX) + (I-PX)\,dX^H\,P^H\Big) \quad&+\; conj \cr
 &= A^*:P\,dX\,(I-PX) + A^*:(I-PX)\,dX^H\,P^H \quad&+\; conj \cr
 &= P^TA^*(I-PX)^T:dX + (I-PX)^TA^*P^*:dX^H \quad&+\; conj \cr
 &= P^TA^*(I-PX)^*:dX + P^HA^H(I-PX):dX^* \quad&+\; conj \cr
\cr
 &= P^TA^*(I-PX)^*:dX + P^HA^H(I-PX):dX^* \cr
 &\;+\; P^HA(I-PX):dX^* + P^TA^T(I-PX)^*:dX \cr
\cr
 &= \Big(P^TA^*(I-PX)^* + P^TA^T(I-PX)^*\Big):dX  \quad&+\; conj \cr 
 &= P^T\,(A+A^H)^T\,(I-PX)^T:dX \quad&+\; conj \cr 
 &= P^T\,(2PX - B-B^H)^T\,(I-PX)^T:dX \quad&+\; conj \cr 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= P^T\,(2PX - B-B^H)^T\,(I-PX)^T \cr 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X^*} &= P^H\,(2PX - B-B^H)^H\,(I-PX)^H \cr
\cr 
}$$
If all of the matrices are in fact *real* $\big($i.e. $X=X^*\big)$, then these Wirtinger derivatives can be combined into a single real result. 
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= 2\,P^T\,(2PX - B-B^T)\,(I-PX) \cr 
}$$
In several places above, a colon is used to denote the trace product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
&A:B &= {\rm Tr}(AB^T) \cr
&A:A^*&= {\rm Tr}(AA^H) = \|A\|_F^2 \cr 
}$$

Comment: It's not a typo. Indeed $(PX)^H=PX$ is one of the _Penrose conditions_ which defines the pseudoinverse.

Comment: @greg, what means the term $+conj$?

Comment: It means I was too lazy to type the _complex conjugate_ of all the terms to the left. But seriously, I think it reduces the "visual clutter"  and makes the whole derivation easier to follow.

Comment: You get some similar results than me. I mean, I got that the gradient is zero when B is the identity matrix and that was strange for me. Is reasonable that the gradient is zero at that case?

Comment: When $B=I$ then the gradient becomes $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial X^*}=-2P^H(I-PX)^2$$ but since $PX$ is an orthoprojector, we have the relationship $(PX)^2=PX$, and also $P^HPX=P^H\,$ (as I mentioned in my answer). These two conditions reduce the gradient to zero.